# Visual Studio Community, Office SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Can Visual Studio Community install Office SDK to develop addins?  I can start an addin project, but in the add new item menu I don't have the options to add things like Ribbons or other C# items and such.  Does this feature only work in the non-community edition?  I do have the office SDK installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix it by installing VS ultimate and checking the Office SDK.